# Getting the specific type of a variable while ensuring it is compatible with its type

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have a type like:

```
type Requirement = {
  name: string;
}
```

And an object conforming to this Requirement type:

```
let some_requirement: Requirement = {
  name: 'SomeRequirement'
}
```

Now suppose we want to use `typeof some_requirement` to enforce another type to match its string literal name

```
type RequirementAssociate<R extends Requirement> = {
  name: R['name']
}

let some_requirement_associate: RequirementAssociate<typeof some_requirement> = {
  name: 'SomeRequirement' // Enforce this to have the same name as some_requirement
}
```

In the above example, TypeScript will enforce that `some_requirement_associate.name` is a `string`, but will not enforce that it is the `string literal` `'SomeRequirement'`

Generally, how can we ensure an object is compatible with a type (`some_requirement: Requirement`), while working with its "specific" type (not sure the term for this), like in the case of enforcing `some_requirement_associate.name` is the string literal `SomeRequirement` above

Comment: Probably you want the upcoming [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR for TS4.9+, use `as const satisfies`, like `const vbl = {⋯} as const satisfies Type`.  See below for the full answer.

---

If you want the compiler to keep track of the specific [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of your object properties, then instead of [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as a wider type and throwing away any such information, you should tell the compiler a hint that you want narrower types. The easiest way to do this is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializing value:

```
let some_requirement = {
    name: 'SomeRequirement'
} as const;
```

which produces the behavior you want:

```
let some_requirement_associate: RequirementAssociate<typeof some_requirement> = {
    name: 'SomeRequiremant' // error!
    //~~ <-- Type '"SomeRequiremant"' is not assignable to type '"SomeRequirement"'
}
```

---

You may be concerned that there's no check that the assigned value satisfies the `Requirement` constraint anymore:

```
let some_bad_requirement = {
    name: 123
} as const; // no error here!
```

There are ways around this, the traditional one is to create a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) identity function as a helper.  But starting in TypeScript 4.9 you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) to check the compatibility without losing the specific type:

```
let some_requirement = {
    name: 'SomeRequirement'
} as const satisfies Requirement; // okay

let some_bad_requirement = {
    name: 123
} as const satisfies Requirement; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

So the combination of `as const` and `satisfies` will allow you to infer very narrow types while still checking against the wider type you care about.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221002#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgWwgO2FAvFAN4BQU5U2AhlgFxQDOwqy2A5gNwkC+JJANhDwMA9lgD66JGkw48hUhUo0I9AOQBlMRDjT0WXGp5QqDKAGMR2JoyrBkDAGbIIZ3Sn1yufUJFgIPWVwAQQZRc2Q7CAAeGCgIAA9gHAATNwCZA2AAPgJiMgpqOlgAbTUiiDUAXR4+QWFtSQzPXHFTcMjk+ndMuVCOqOjfCBFHRkapQKzchQLyCvUtLB79KkMoAHoN+NRUEVQAQjnNjYA-U6hogForqAAVcGg1ACIlnWbMNeBntSgHShEeHayDY1AARoIoMARFDHlAXm8VkFvkZeAIhOMJGCqCkmnpkXlFIUVPQAIwAJgAzMZTBYrDYGHYHM5XP58VkOCcdntDiQtvc4eVEBgwRBUL9-thASYwiDwZDobC-GomCx2EYgA)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not just a

```
type Requirement = {
  name: string;
}
```

What you want is

```
type NamedRequirement<Name extends string> = {
  name: Name;
}
let some_requirement_n: NamedRequirement<'SomeRequirement'> = {
  name: 'SomeRequirement'
} as const
// or 
let some_requirement_c /* const type */ = {
  name: 'SomeRequirement'
} as const
```

otherwise name type will be lost in `string`
then what you did will work in both cases